# Webpack resolve.fallback not working. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in node_modules\aws4

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, cryptography, vue-cli

I have a nodejs app created through the Vue CLI. I need to use the aws4 node module to sign my requests. However, when I use the aws4 module the app fails to serve due to the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/aws4/aws4.js 4:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\henry\Repos\AWS4 TEST\aws4-test\node_modules\aws4'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

I got this error for the 3 imports in the aws module: crypto, url and querystring.

I read the error message and saw that the version of webpack the vue cli uses is 5+ so the core modules such as crypto are not included anymore.

(I've never really used webpack before, but the instructions seems simple.)

I created a new file in my project webpack.config.js and added the following:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
    },
  },
};
```

I then installed the crypto-browserify package.

I still get the error, it's make 0 difference.

I've looked online and have tried solutions suggested for the crypto not found issue. None of them seem to work either. I've tried:

- Adding this to the package.json

```
"browser": {
    "crypto": false
}
```

- Adding the crypto object to the paths object in tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
   "crypto": ["node_modules/crypto-browerify"],
}
```

- I tried using the node module: node-polyfill-webpack-plugin. Which did resolve the issue for url and querystring (as soon as the module was imported). But the issue with crypto remains.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "aws4-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws4": "^1.11.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws4": "^1.11.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^1.1.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
}
```

To isolate the issue I created a new vue 2 app though the cli then just added the aws4 and axios modules. The fact that the node-polyfill-webpack-plugin works to resolve the errors for all but crypto error seems odd. Perhaps something else is overwritting that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what if you try:
{
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      'crypto': false,
      'crypto-browserify': require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
    },
  },
}

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sadly it still didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the webpack config wasn't working was because I am using the vue-cli-service. So to configure the webpack config I needed to edit the vue.config.js file and use the configureWebpack object. Docs here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html

Comment: I'm sorry, do you have solution's code implementation? Been struggling with the same issue

Comment: @CraZyCoDer This is my vue.config.js file


`const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
    ],
  },
});
`